# Custom delegate is always nil in UITableViewController in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, delegates, protocols

I am trying to implement custom delegate in my project. Delegate is always nil in my case I don't know what am I doing wrong here ?

I have table view controller and I am using custom cell. Custom cell has few labels. I am adding Tap gesture for one of the label. When user tap on label, Pop over controller open and when user select the item then delegate from that viewcontroller return the value for label and this action is taking care by delegate.

I implemented same thing in Objective C and it is working fine but in swift my delegate is always nil. Please help me with it.

Here is my code

ABCTableViewController.swift

```
        var cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier:"cell" as String)

        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell1", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

        let popover = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("dropdown") as! DropDownViewController
        (cell as! labelCell).popOverTableVC = popover
    }
```

LabelCell.swift

```
{
    self.label.userInteractionEnabled = true
    var recog = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "someAction")
    self.brandNameLabel .addGestureRecognizer(recog)
}

func someAction()
{
self.popOverTableVC.delegate = self
}

// Delegate implementation 
func selectedItem (item: NSString)
{
    self.label.text = item as String

    self.popOver .dismissPopoverAnimated(true)
}
```

DropDownViewController.swift

```
protocol DropDownViewControllerDelegate: class
{
func selectedItem (item: NSString)
}

weak var delegate: DropDownViewControllerDelegate? = nil

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var selectedItem: NSString = "Hello From Delegate"
    if (self.delegate != nil)
    {
        self.delegate?.selectedItem(selectedItem)
    }
}
```

in didSelectRowAtIndexPath, self.delegate is always nil.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something. You set your delegate in the `recog()` method. But where do you call that `recog()` method?

Comment: my bad. it is added in UITapGestureRecognizer.

Comment: You have a variable named recog which is your UITapGestureRecognizer and then you have your recog() function, where you assign your delegate, but I don't see you calling that method anywhere. Couldn't that be the problem?

Comment: recog is instance of the UITapGestureRecognizer and and someAction is where I am setting up and delegate.

Comment: OK, I'm beginning to see where you're going now :-). Right...back to debugging then. If you place a breakpoint in your `someAction()` method, can you see it being called when you tab your `brandNameLabel`?